# Can you make a PHP bookmarklet?

Tags: php, xml, httprequest

Is there a way to make a PHP bookmarklet? This is what I'm thinking:

```
javascript:(function(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
xmlhttp.open("GET", "echo.php?e=Hello");
xmlhttp.send();
}
} 
)()
```

And the `echo.php` file:

```
<?php
$e = $_REQUEST['p'];
if (e) {
echo '$e';
}
?>
```

I must use a bookmarklet because extentions and the developer console would not work for me.
Would this work? I'm not very familiar with XML Http requests, so please bear with me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bookmarklet can reference some PHP script that lives on a reachable and properly configured somehwere, but you cannot put actual PHP in anything that executes in the browser as that's not how or where PHP is executed.

Comment: So an http request to the server wouldn't work?

Comment: The opposite. An HTTP request to a remote server is the _only_ way it will work.

Comment: Okay, I see. An http request will return data. But is there a way to run a function server-side instead of just returning data?